# Error text is cut off when generated to PDF in nuxt.js + @nuxtjs/tailwindcss

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Error text is cut off when generated from HTML to PDF with Vue-html2pdf in Nuxt.js when use @nuxtjs/tailwindcss although when show layout then everything is normal.

**View when generated pdf**
[image]

The cause is @nuxtjs/tailwindcss, when @nuxtjs/tailwindcss is removed, everything is normal. How can I use @nuxtjs/tailwindcss and vue-html2pdf at the same time?

**My Code**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="$refs.html2Pdf.generatePdf()">Click</button>
    <vue-html2pdf
      ref="html2Pdf"
      :show-layout="false"
      :float-layout="true"
      :enable-download="true"
      :preview-modal="true"
      :paginate-elements-by-height="1400"
      filename="hee hee"
      :pdf-quality="2"
      :manual-pagination="false"
      pdf-format="a4"
      pdf-orientation="landscape"
      pdf-content-width="800px"
    >
      <section slot="pdf-content">
        <div style="background-color: red">
          Hello World
        </div>
      </section>
    </vue-html2pdf>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: You should post an issue in the vue project or even in the [JS one](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js) (if you achieve to reproduce it with vanilla JS).

Comment: Also, you could maybe try [Windi](https://windicss.org/) and see if you have the issue?

Comment: tks, but The project I'm working on is too big, so I can't change tailwind to another framework

Comment: Give a read to Windi still please. It's not like you're going from Bootstrap to Tailwind here. Windi is compatible with Tailwind at around 95% let's say, so if you're not using some bleeding edge features of Tailwind, you should still be pretty good. Even [UnoCSS](https://antfu.me/posts/reimagine-atomic-css) could work in your case. Otherwise, you could maybe make it on the backend, rather than in your Nuxt app.

Comment: Or look for another JS library maybe. A [canvas export](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) may be an alternative? If your project is big and it was not considered (and PoC'ed) initially, it will still require some lifting at some places anyway.

Comment: I tried. but text taken from html2pdf is still cropped

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem here.

Here below follow the step necessarys to solve it.

Visiting https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight on Images are block-level, you will see on CSS file the line < display: block; >

We just changed from block to inline.

Appears that Tailwild goes up of Canva whem you are using HTML2PDF.

The solution is that, hope to help, tks, our gretings.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your tailwind.css file or global.css

```
//wherever u are using this
//@tailwind base;
//@tailwind components;
//@tailwind utilities;
```

Replace it with This

```
@tailwind base;
@layer base {
  img {
    @apply inline-block;
  }
}
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

This is what it worked for me and explanation is already done by @Ana Frozza 's Solution